# GroupBy Expression failed to translate

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

```
//Model
public class Application
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConfirmedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssuedDate { get; set; }
    public int? AddedByUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User AddedByUser { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedByuser { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TRN { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int ParishId { get; set; }
    public Parish Parish { get; set; }
    public int? BranchIssuedId { get; set; }
    public BranchLocation BranchIssued { get; set; }
    public int? BranchReceivedId { get; set; }
    public BranchLocation BranchReceived {get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<Application>> GetApplicationsByNameAsync(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return null;
    return await _context.Application
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(app => app.BranchIssued)
        .Include(app => app.BranchReceived)
        .Include(app => app.Parish)
        .Where(app => app.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) || app.FirstName.ToLower()
        .Contains(name.ToLower()))
        .GroupBy(app => new { app.TRN, app })
        .Select(x => x.Key.app)
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The above `GroupBy` expression fails to compile in VS Studio. My objective is to run a query filtering results by name containing a user given string and then it should group the results by similar `TRN` numbers returning a list of those applications to return to the view. I think I am really close but just cant seem to figure out this last bit of the query. Any guidance is appreciated.

Error being presented

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Application>
.Where(a => a.LastName.ToLower().Contains(__ToLower_0) || a.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(__ToLower_0))
.GroupBy(
source: a => new {
TRN = a.TRN,
app = a
},
keySelector: a => a)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

**UPDATE**
Seems it is definitely due to a change in how .net core 3.x and EF core play together since recent updates. I had to change it to client evaluation by using `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToListAsync()`. The rest of the query given by Steve py works with this method. I was unaware even after reading docs how the groupby really worked in LINQ, so that has helped me a lot. Taking the query to client side eval may have performance issues however.

Comment: Compile-time or run-time error? Which line is highlighted? Maybe change `.GroupBy(app => new { app.TRN, app })` to `.GroupBy(app => app.TRN)`?

Comment: @JohnyL I added the error to the question as an edit. I did try that indeed, but I need the output from the query to be in the form of  `List<Application>`

Comment: Did changing `.GroupBy(app => new { app.TRN, app })` to `.GroupBy(app => app.TRN)` helped?

Comment: No it still didnt give me the proper result set, unfortunately. Hmm maybe I should tackle this a different way. I want to group by TRN which is a repeating set of numbers eg.12345, in the Application table there may be many records with that same sequence and I only want the very latest row within each set of TRN sequences. So if the table has 3 rows with that TRN I want only the last inserted row to be returned. This is what I am trying to achieve for every distinct set of TRN numbers

Comment: I rolled back your last revision because it changes the question into a new question, which doesn't respect existing answers.

Comment: Also, it's a known issue that EF core 3 doesn't support GroupBy well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

> I want to group by TRN which is a repeating set of numbers eg.12345, in the Application table there may be many records with that same sequence and I only want the very latest row within each set of TRN sequences.

I believe this should satisfy what you are looking for:

```
return await _context.Application
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(app => app.BranchIssued)
    .Include(app => app.BranchReceived)
    .Include(app => app.Parish)
    .Where(app => app.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) || app.FirstName.ToLower()
    .Contains(name.ToLower()))
    .GroupBy(app => app.TRN)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedAt).First())
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The `GroupBy` expression should represent what you want to group by. In your case, the TRN. From there when we do the select, `x` represents each "group" which contains the Enumarable set of Applications that fall under each TRN. So we order those by the descending CreatedAt date to select the newest one using `First`.

Give that a shot. If it's not quite what you're after, consider adding an example set to your question and the desired output vs. what output / error this here produces.

Comment: Actually you have helped explain groupby a bit more for me, I wasn't thinking along the lines of the groups being actual "groups" of items. I will give it a try and report the results

Comment: `could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly ` thats a snippet of the error I get when trying to run the query as you have it outlined. I am using .net core 3.0, not sure if that has anything to do with it at the moment.

Comment: That error indicates that there is something in the expression that EF Core cannot translate to SQL. I think this may be a breaking change in EF Core 3 as I've tested an expression like that in EF Core 2.6 and EF 6 and they translate fine. If you are running SQL Server as the DB, the extra ToLower() for string comparison are not needed provided the default case insensitive collation is used.  I tried updating my test project from 2.6 to 3.0 and it threw a hissy fit about my entity configuration due to some breaking change in modelbuilder. EF Core team is a dysfunctional mess IMO ...

Comment: can you try `.Where(app => app.LastName.Contains(name) || app.FirstName.Contains(name))`. I know it's not an ideal solution as it makes assumptions about collation, but it might confirm or deny where the problem lies.

Comment: Meant to add, the original `ToLower` statements generated with Core 2.6 resulted in: `WHERE (CHARINDEX(@__ToLower_0, LOWER([x].[Name])) > 0) OR (@__ToLower_0 = N'''')',` with no client evaluation. So it may be a quirk with Core 3, or specific to your example somehow.

Comment: Any other leads as to how to work around this new error?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it looks like as of .net core 3.0 you have to break up the query to client side evaluation and use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList()` at some point. I will do more testing and if it works I will update my question to answer it I guess. So far it seems specific to 3.0+=

Comment: Are you grouping on just `a.TRN`, not `new { a.TRN, a}`?  Can you add an edit to your question with the current Linq expression and resulting error message? Once that is confirmed, if there is still an error, try removing the `ToLower` from `app.LastName` and `app.FirstName` to see if that triggering the issue. Seeing the updated Expression though may point out an issue still in the query.  With EF Core 3 there is a setting on the DbContext to allow the auto-client side eval (removing the error) but I don't recommend that or manually doing it because it will result in performance issues.

Comment: Definitely only grouping by a.TRN, i do believe it is because of .net core 3.0 and EF not playing well together since update.

Answer (score 7):

The GroupBy support in EF core is a joke.

This worked perfectly on the server in EF6

```
var nonUniqueGroups2 = db.Transactions.GroupBy(e => new { e.AccountId, e.OpeningDate })
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

In EF core it causes an exception "Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side." The message is misleading, do not call `AsEnumerable` because this should be handled on the server.

I have found a workaround [here](https://tipsfordev.com/groupby-can-t-be-translated). An additional `Select` will help.

```
                var nonUniqueGroups = db.Transactions.GroupBy(e => new { e.AccountId, e.OpeningDate })
                    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                    .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
                    .ToList();
```

The drawback of the workaround is that the result set does not contain the items in the groups.

There is an EF Core [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068#issuecomment-586464350). Please vote on it so they actually fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I experience a similar issue where I find it interesting and stupid at the same time. Seems like EF team prohibits doing a WHERE before GROUP BY hence it does not work. I don't understand why you cannot do it but this seems the way it is which is forcing me to implement procedures instead of nicely build code.

LMK if you find a way.

Note: They have group by only when you first group then do where (where on the grouped elements of the complete table => does not make any sense to me)

Comment: alternatively (if you can bear than), select everything to memory after your filter and group it in memory. I don't like to get all data from SQL to client end as it is too much data flow and slows down everything.

Answer (score 0):

The query below works in EF6 but fails in EF Core with the error *"The LINQ expression ... could not be translated"*:

```
var duplicates = db.Orders
    .GroupBy(x => x.ExternalId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToList();
```

In fact, EF6 could not translate the whole query to SQL too, but instead, it silently translates to SQL only the first part: `db.Orders.GroupBy(x => x.ExternalId)`, runs it to read everything into memory and then executes the `Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` filtering there. Of course, this might cause performance and memory issues. Because of this the EF Core simply does not allow such implicit database reading (and offers to do this explicitly in the exception message).

To get the given LINQ fully translated to SQL for EF Core we need to use one extra `select` and unfortunately don't read all group items. If we still need to know group items we can return all their Ids in one field:

```
var duplicates = db.Orders
    .GroupBy(x => x.ExternalId)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count(), Ids = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Id))})
    .Where(g => g.Count > 1)
    .ToList();
```